# Iterate an array in Angular JS to have a common code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having 3 lines of code, where only the extension is changed. Tomorrow there may be 10 lines. I don't want to have multiple lines of simple code. I'm trying to keep all the required values in an array and iterate and assign them to an object. However its failing. Here is my code

```
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
  $scope.accounts[i].name = $scope.accounts[i].name ? $scope.accounts[i].name : []
}
```

I've commented out the code which i dont want. Am I missing anything here? Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/SyedNizamChennai/kjuemhua/40/

Comment: it would be easier to use array concat. Where did u getting 'accounts'. post ur full code.

Comment: @FazalRasel, I'm going to use accounts1 & accounts2 & accounts3 for ng-repeate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answers are wrong. $scope.accounts[1] means the first object for the accounts array. You have no array.

The correct approach would be the following.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    $scope["accounts" + i] = $scope["accounts" + i] || []
}
```

Also not that `$scope["accounts" + i] || []` is the same as `$scope["accounts" + i] ? $scope["accounts" + i] : []`

Answer (score 1):

Arrays is always counts from 0 index:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  $scope.accounts[i].name = $scope.accounts[i].name ? $scope.accounts[i].name : []
}
```

Comment: + you shouldn't use "3" in hard, but $scope.accounts.length.

Answer (score 0):

your for loop is wrong 
[fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/kjuemhua/44/)

```
$scope.accounts=[{name:"accounts1"},{name:"accounts2"},{name:"accounts3"}];

for(var i = 0; i < $scope.accounts.length; i++){
  $scope.accounts[i].name = $scope.accounts[i].name ? $scope.accounts[i].name : []
}
```

Comment: Doron, my statement should be equal to $scope.accounts1 = $scope.accounts1 ? $scope.accounts1 : []; because I'm iterating "accounts1" & so on object in ng-repeat